# Create Three dimensional array and assign value to it in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have tried to create 3 dimensional array and assigning value to it, base on the answer here [creating and parsing a 3D array in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943633/creating-and-parsing-a-3d-array-in-javascript) .

```
var myArr = new Array(new Array(new Array()));

myArr[0][0][0] = "1";
myArr[0][0][1] = "2";
myArr[0][1][0] = "2";
myArr[0][1][1] = "2";
myArr[0][2][0] = "3";
myArr[0][2][1] = "4";
```

but I get this

> Uncaught Typeerror: Cannot set propterty '0' of undefined".

Need some help.

Thank you

Comment: The problem here is that `var myArr = new Array(new Array(new Array()));` translates to `myArr[0][0] = [ ]` meaning that when trying to access `myArr[0][1]` you get an undefined object, since in fact, you never created an array at that index.

Comment: There are no multidimensional arrays in JS, you can only emulate them with nested arrays. This means, that you've to define every member separately as a subarray.

Comment: @Teemu : Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: I'm sure you can create the nested loops needed for task without any example.

Answer (score 1):

There are no initiating variables in advance in javascript and the compilation step simply hoists top-level variable and function definitions, and in ES6, does static importing and exporting (though that's not yet natively supported)[Patrick Roberts]. One additional option is

```
var myArr = new Array();
myArr[0] = new Array();
myArr[0][0] = new Array();
myArr[0][0][0] = "1";
myArr[0][0][1] = "2";
myArr[0][1] = new Array();
myArr[0][1][0] = "2";
myArr[0][1][1] = "2";
myArr[0][2] = new Array();
myArr[0][2][0] = "3";
myArr[0][2][1] = "4";
```

Comment: sorry i meant java script, fixing

Comment: Technically there is a compile-time, since it's a JIT compiled language. The compilation step simply hoists top-level variable and function definitions, and in ES6, does static importing and exporting (though that's not yet natively supported).

Comment: @Legman why there is no semi colon at the line 3? myArr[0][0] = new Array()

Comment: Typo, it has been fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this (but creating 3d array in javascript is more completed stuff. Please consider changing your approach to handle data):

```js
var myArr = new Array();
myArr[0] = new Array();
myArr[0][0] = new Array();
myArr[0][0][0] = "1";
myArr[0][0][1] = "2";
myArr[0][1] = new Array();
myArr[0][1][0] = "2";
myArr[0][1][1] = "2";
myArr[0][2] = new Array();
myArr[0][2][0] = "3";
myArr[0][2][1] = "4";

console.log(myArr[0][2][0]);
```